# I want to compare two coloumns in excel and print the values of the matched rows in other coloumn in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to compare two coloumns in excel and print the values of the matched rows in other coloumn in excel...

We have three coloumns A1,B1,C1.. we want to compare A1 and B1 if rows matches we want to print the values of desired C1 rows...

Comment: Hi Pramod, welcome to SuperUser.  This isn't really a good question for this site, http://www.http://stackoverflow.com/ would be a better fit.  Also, they'll want to see some code - what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Cell in Row C:

```
=IF(A1=B1,"result","")
```

Instead of "result" you could put A1 or B1 or whatever you want.

Comment: Ya it's fine friend.. but i want to print the values of Coloumn C1.. itried that but don't work

Comment: @user - wasn't ripping off your answer, I just hit submit and yours had just notified "new answer" :/

Comment: you know any other solutions using some other formulas like VLOOKUP or MATCH

Comment: @PramodPrem - see my edit.

Comment: @PramodPrem You might want to clarify what you mean exactly. And do post what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to research `if` in Excel.  You'll end up with something like this:

```
=IF(A1>B1, "Larger", "Smaller")
```

Basically:

- Compare
- What to do if true
- What to do if false

---

*EDIT*

From your comment:

```
=IF(A1>B1,C1,"")
```

should work.

---

*EDIT 2*

If you want to compare one cell to a range:

```
=INDEX(C7:G7,MATCH(C10,C7:G7,0))
```

Discussed [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/87031-formula-compare-value-one-cell-range-5-cells.html) and [here](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/685465-if-one-cell-equals-a-range-of-cells-return-with-true-or-false.html).

Comment: just assume coloumn A1 have 5000 rows and Coloumn B1 have only 120 rows remaining blank.. iwant to compare these. we get the matching rows after that i want to print the coloumn C1 'a value

Comment: Yeah, that's why we'll need some code to really understand your problem.  Give me a second I'll try to figure it out.  (A1 and B1 are cells, btw)

Comment: Actually there's no way anyone can understand what you mean without an example. Do you want to compare each of the 120 values to each of the 5000 values? Or, straight across? Or, what? Anyway, had a stab at it, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think, I found something similar to what you're looking for, through this question:

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3417-excel-compare-two-columns-and-return-value-from-third.html